# Convert milliseconds to an ISO 8601 duration

Tags: javascript, momentjs, duration, iso8601

What is the easiest way to convert a time duration in milliseconds to an ISO 8601 duration using Moment.js?

For example:

```
3600000 milliseconds > PT1H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
// Duration 1 hour
var duration = moment.duration(1, 'h');
console.log( duration.asMilliseconds() )   // 3600000

// Convert to ISO8601 duration string
console.log( duration.toISOString() )      // "PT1H"
```

Also, 5 minutes like:

```
var duration = moment.duration(5, 'm');
console.log( duration.asMilliseconds() )   // 300000

// Convert to ISO8601 duration string
console.log( duration.toISOString() )      // "PT5M"
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this is currently one of the top results when searching for how to convert milliseconds to an [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) with JavaScript, here is an approach using vanilla JS for those that can't or don't want to use Moment.js.

```js
const duration = (ms) => {
  const dt = new Date(ms);
  const units = [
    ['Y', dt.getUTCFullYear() - 1970],
    ['M', dt.getUTCMonth()],
    ['D', dt.getUTCDate() - 1],
    ['T', null],
    ['H', dt.getUTCHours()],
    ['M', dt.getUTCMinutes()],
    ['S', dt.getUTCSeconds()]
  ];
  
  let str = units.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if (v) {
      acc += v + k;
    } else if (k === 'T') {
      acc += k;
    } 
    return acc;
  }, '');
  
  str = str.endsWith('T') ? str.slice(0, -1) : str;
  return str ? `P${str}` : null;
};

console.log(duration(110723405000));
// P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S
console.log(duration(3600000));
// PT1H
```

Comment: This does not deal with fractional seconds. I have modified the last element in `elems` to the following for my use-case: `['S', `${dt.getUTCSeconds()}.${dt.getUTCMilliseconds()}`]`